# Correct result for MySQL query using LEFT JOIN and History table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i would like to create query which returns status for meters in apartment.

I have tables BR_Apartment, BR_Meter and BR_Parameter_Value.
Default value for meter status is active (1) all history data was stored in BR_Parameter_Value table when status has changed.

I need only last status for meters in apartment or default value. 
Current query returns all records from BR_Parameter_Value.

Example of my query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08165/1/0)

Can someone correct me if I am building my query incorrectly or educate me with a few tips on how to properly accomplish what I want to do?

**Edit:**

I've updated example based on answer from Gordon which works if date is `NOW()` but I would like to use same query for history values as well to get meter status based on specific date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get the most recent parameter value from the parameter table (just the addition of the `exists` statement in the `where` clause):

```
SELECT m.*, IFNULL( pva.ParameterValue, 1 ) AS MeterIsActive,
       IF( pva.ParameterValue <1, 'meterNotActive', '' ) AS MeterTypeClass
FROM BR_Meter m INNER JOIN
     BR_Apartment a
     ON ( m.ApartmentID = a.ApartmentID ) LEFT JOIN
     BR_Parameter_Value pva
     ON ( pva.ForeignID = m.MeterID AND
          pva.ParameterDate <= NOW( ) AND
          pva.ParameterID =12
        ) 
WHERE m.ApartmentID = 2452 and
      (not exists (select 1
                   from BR_Parameter_value pv2
                   where pv2.ForeignID = pva.ForeignID and
                         pv2.parameterid = pva.parameterid and
                         pv2.ParameterDate > pva.ParameterDate
                  )
      )
```

I don't know what you mean by default value.